# Laravel. I can't read the data from the column

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem.
Needs to get the first date of creation of data in the table by the currently logged in user.

***Working example:***

```
$howMuchIPlay = Game::all('user_id')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->count();
```

***Not working example:***

```
$firstVoteInGame = Game::all('created_at')->first()->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id);
```

When I use count() function I get value 38. This is all the rows for the user, but I want to get only the earliest (first). How can I do this?

Sorry for my english and thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Move the `->first()` after the `where()`

Comment: @apokryfos now dd returns me null

Comment: Sidenote: `all()` will actually get all data from the table, you might want to do `Game::where(...)->[count()/first()]` instead

Comment: It works, thx for help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$firstVoteInGame = Game::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->oldest()->first();
```

This will get the earliest (oldest) record from the current authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

You got the order wrong.

You should first limit by user Id.

Then order by created at in descending order so oldest is on top. Or if you want the newest, order by `'desc'` instead of `'asc'`

Then get the first.

```
Game::where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','asc')->first();
```

What you did was:

Get all records from database in a collection.
get first possible record from collection at index 0
limit a model object by a where query(it would fail here since you were in a model object, not a collection or query builder instance);

Answer (score 1):

Your not working example, `$firstVoteInGame = Game::all('created_at')->first()->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id);`, starts off with `Game::all('created_at')`.

What this means is that all `Game`s are returned, but these are limited to the 'created_at' column only (see the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all)).

Since you're limiting your result to the 'created_at' column, Eloquent will now not be able to compare the 'user_id' columns to the authenticated user id.

In addition, even if you were to select all columns (by performing `Game::all()`), you are calling `->first()` after which you only have the first row remaining.

You say you want to

> get the first date of creation of data in the table by the currently logged in user.

This would thus by done by:

```
$firstVoteInGame = Game::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','asc')->first('created_at');
```

Comment: The difference lies in how much data is returned by the SQL server. In my example, only the `created_at` column is returned (which contains exactly the data you need). Without the `created_at`, the entire row is returned (Which in some situations might not be desirable, for example when returning a large number of rows - not applicable in this case - or if the rows are very wide)

Answer (score 0):

Why you use 'created_at' for ordering as easy/correct way is use primary key, Because you can just do:

```
$firstVoteInGame = Game::where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

You can try, if you still want 'created_at':

```
$firstVoteInGame = Game::where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

*TIP* 
- The Eloquent `all` method will return all of the results in the model's table so avoid to use it with `first` method